# SQL find effective price of the products based on the date

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table with four columns : id,validFrom,validTo and price.
This table contains the price of an article and the duration when that price is effective.

```
| id| validFrom |  validTo  | price
|---|-----------|-----------|---------  
| 1 | 01-01-17  | 10-01-17  | 30000   
| 1 | 04-01-17  | 09-01-17  | 20000
```

Now, for this inputs in my table my query output should be :

```
| id| validFrom | validTo  | price  
|---|-----------|----------|-------
| 1 | 01-01-17  | 03-01-17 | 30000  
| 1 | 04-01-17  | 09-01-17 | 20000  
| 1 | 10-01-17  | 10-01-17 | 30000
```

I can compare the dates and check if products with same id have overlapping dates but I have no idea how to split those dates into non-overlapping dates. Also I am not allowed to use PL/SQL.
Is this possible using only SQL ?

Comment: Use a calendar table to generate the ranges you want in your output, and then join against your original table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, I don't get you. The date ranges will be based on the entries of the table. How do I use a calendar table to get the ranges?
Can you please point me to some links/resources for calendar tables? I am new to this

Comment: Is it possible that one interval intersects another but does not contain it?

Comment: How do you decide which price "wins" if two (or more) prices overlap in some day?. Say you have 3 different prices for the same interval, which one do you want to use?

Comment: @Aleksej From what I have understood if two or more prices overlap in some day the price with shortest duration will be considered.

This is actually a retail market scenario. Normally, Product A is priced X,but due to some sale the price gets reduced to Y but for a certain duration so we consider that new price.

Comment: ok, but what if you have two different prices for the same interval, say both for the same, single day? the lowest one?

Comment: @Aleksej yes we will go with the lowest one

Answer (score 3):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE prices ( id, validFrom, validTo, price ) AS
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-01', DATE '2017-01-10', 30000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-04', DATE '2017-01-09', 20000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-11', DATE '2017-01-15', 10000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-16', DATE '2017-01-18', 15000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-17', DATE '2017-01-20', 40000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-21', DATE '2017-01-24', 28000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-23', DATE '2017-01-26', 23000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE '2017-01-26', DATE '2017-01-26', 17000 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH daily_prices ( id, dt, price, duration ) AS (
  -- Unroll the price ranges to individual days
  SELECT id,
         d.COLUMN_VALUE,
         price,
         validTo - validFrom
  FROM   prices p,
         TABLE(
           CAST(
             MULTISET(
               SELECT p.validFrom + LEVEL - 1
               FROM   DUAL
               CONNECT BY p.validFrom + LEVEL - 1 <= p.validTo
             )
             AS SYS.ODCIDATELIST
           )
         ) d
),
min_daily_prices ( id, dt, price ) AS (
  -- Where a day falls between multiple ranges group them so the price
  -- is for the shortest duration offer and if there are two equally short
  -- durations then take the minimum price
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         MIN( price ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY duration )
  FROM   daily_prices
  GROUP BY id, dt
),
group_changes ( id, dt, price, has_changed_group ) AS (
  -- Find when the price changes or a day is skipped which means a new price
  -- group is beginning
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         price,
         CASE WHEN dt    = LAG( dt    ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt ) + 1
              AND  price = LAG( price ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt )
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
              END
  FROM   min_daily_prices
),
groups ( id, dt, price, grp ) AS (
  -- Calculate unique indexes (per id) for each group of price ranges
  SELECT id,
         dt,
         price,
         SUM( has_changed_group ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY dt )
  FROM   group_changes
)
SELECT id,
       MIN( dt ) AS validFrom,
       MAX( dt ) AS validTo,
       MIN( price ) AS price
FROM   groups
GROUP BY id, grp
ORDER BY id, validFrom;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID VALIDFROM            VALIDTO                   PRICE
---------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------
         1 01-JAN-2017 00:00:00 03-JAN-2017 00:00:00      30000
         1 04-JAN-2017 00:00:00 09-JAN-2017 00:00:00      20000
         1 10-JAN-2017 00:00:00 10-JAN-2017 00:00:00      30000
         1 11-JAN-2017 00:00:00 15-JAN-2017 00:00:00      10000
         1 16-JAN-2017 00:00:00 18-JAN-2017 00:00:00      15000
         1 19-JAN-2017 00:00:00 20-JAN-2017 00:00:00      40000
         1 21-JAN-2017 00:00:00 22-JAN-2017 00:00:00      28000
         1 23-JAN-2017 00:00:00 25-JAN-2017 00:00:00      23000
         1 26-JAN-2017 00:00:00 26-JAN-2017 00:00:00      17000
```

Comment: Thanks! Your output is perfect but when I'm running this query with the inputs I provided i.e. just the two rows I am getting [this result](http://pasteboard.co/iozEUMh4j.png).

Can you please look at that?

Comment: @noobCoder The only way I have found of getting your results is if the dates have a time component (which is not being displayed but may still exist) - try do `SELECT id, TO_CHAR( validFrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS validFrom, TO_CHAR( validTo, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS validTo, price FROM pricetable` and you will see the time components.

Comment: Or you can change the way SQL developer displays dates by going to `Tools > Preferences > Database > NLS` and modify the date format to something like `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` and then re-running the query and you should see the time components.

Comment: One way to "fix" this is to change the first section to `MULTISET( SELECT TRUNC( p.validFrom ) + LEVEL - 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY TRUNC( p.validFrom ) + LEVEL - 1 <= TRUNC( p.validTo ) )` but this will strip the time components from the dates.